# Как исправить логику с if?

Tags: c#, if

Если первое слово является номером телефона, то в консоль так же пишется, что обе строчки не телефон, как можно было бы исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        private void regeTelephone(string first_word, string second_word)  // ЧЕТВЕРТАЯ ПРОВЕРКА
    {
        string regex = "^\\+?[1-9][0-9]{7,14}$";



        if (Regex.IsMatch(first_word, regex))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(first_word + " Строка является номером телефона ");

        }

        if (Regex.IsMatch(second_word, regex))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(second_word + " Строка является номером телефона ");

        }
        else
        {
            throw new ValidationException("Строчки не являются номером телефона");
        }
```

Comment: Говорите про телефон, а в коде везде IP. А так, `else if` в помощь.

Comment: перед вторым if добавьте else

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `if`, **`else if`** и `else`

```
private const string phoneRegex = "^\\+?[1-9][0-9]{7,14}$";
private void RegexTelephone(string first_word, string second_word)  // ЧЕТВЕРТАЯ ПРОВЕРКА
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(first_word, phoneRegex))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{first_word} является номером телефона");
    }
    else if (Regex.IsMatch(second_word, phoneRegex))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{second_word} является номером телефона");
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ValidationException("Строчки не являются номером телефона");
    }
}
```